# Combo Box Dependiente c#, wpf

Tags: c#, combobox

tengo un duda respecto a como generar un conbo box deoendiente en c# wpf

A combo box dependiente me refiero a que al momento de seleccionar una opción, otro combo box muestre distintos valores respecto a la opción escogida ej:

ComboA: perro - - > comboB:ladrar
ComboA:gato - - > comboB: maullar

En este ejemplo se usan el combo a y b en donde el combo a al escoger la opción "perro" cambia los atributos de combo box b a ladrar, sin embargo, al escoger gato me dara a escoger la opción maullar

La cosa es que quiero que el combo box b cambie los datos respecto al valor seleccionado en el a, de manera que no me muestre todos los valores posibles

Muchas gracias por su atención

Si no entendieron dejo un link de lo que necesito pero en windows form,  cosa que necesito en wpf

Comment: Que has intentado hasta ahora??

Comment: Bienvenido Alvaro... Para saber como funciona el sitio te recomiendo hagas un [tour]... Y para evitar que tu publicación tenga puntuaciones negativas o reportes te recomiendo que vayas a [ask] y luego edites la pregunta según corresponda, tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y no nos das suficiente información para ayudarte...